# moving child nodes to another <g> element mess up the design

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have a working static svg graph with root node and 4 child nodes. I wanted to group the child nodes separately but that way the design gets broken up. Here is the working code

```html
<svg id="svg" width="800" height="600" viewbox="0 0 800 600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g id="root_node" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 250 100)">
          <rect width="200" height="60" rx="5" ry="5">
          </rect>
          <text x="100" y="30" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" fill="white">
            Root Node
          </text>   
          <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="0" transform="translate(0, 0) rotate(-135)" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
          <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="0" transform="translate(200 0) rotate(-45)" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
          <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="0" transform="translate(0 60) rotate(135)" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
          <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="0" transform="translate(200 60) rotate(45)" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
        </g>
        <g id="child_node">
          <rect width="180" height="60" x="0" y="0" rx="5" ry="5">
          </rect>
          <rect width="180" height="60" x="500" y="0" rx="5" ry="5">
          </rect>
          <rect width="180" height="60" x="0" y="200" rx="5" ry="5">
          </rect>
          <rect width="180" height="60" x="500" y="200" rx="5" ry="5">
          </rect>
          <text x="100" y="30" font-size="14" fill="white" text-anchor="middle">Child Node 1</text>
          <text x="600" y="30" font-size="14" fill="white" text-anchor="middle">Child Node 2</text>
          <text x="100" y="230" font-size="14" fill="white" text-anchor="middle">Child Node 3</text>
          <text x="600" y="230" font-size="14" fill="white" text-anchor="middle">Child Node 4</text>
        </g>
        <g id="edges">
          
        </g>
      </svg>
```

when i changed the above code to following where I wanted to group the child node in one place, i dont get the above design

```html
 <svg id="svg" width="800" height="600" viewbox="0 0 800 600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g id="root_node" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 250 100)">
          <rect width="200" height="60" rx="5" ry="5">
          </rect>
          <text x="100" y="30" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" fill="white">
            Root Node
          </text>
        </g>
        <g id="child_node">
          <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="0" transform="translate(0, 0) rotate(-135)" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
          <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="0" transform="translate(200 0) rotate(-45)" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
          <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="0" transform="translate(0 60) rotate(135)" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
          <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="0" transform="translate(200 60) rotate(45)" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
          
          <rect width="180" height="60" x="0" y="0" rx="5" ry="5">
          </rect>
          <rect width="180" height="60" x="500" y="0" rx="5" ry="5">
          </rect>
          <rect width="180" height="60" x="0" y="200" rx="5" ry="5">
          </rect>
          <rect width="180" height="60" x="500" y="200" rx="5" ry="5">
          </rect>
          <text x="100" y="30" font-size="14" fill="white" text-anchor="middle">Child Node 1</text>
          <text x="600" y="30" font-size="14" fill="white" text-anchor="middle">Child Node 2</text>
          <text x="100" y="230" font-size="14" fill="white" text-anchor="middle">Child Node 3</text>
          <text x="600" y="230" font-size="14" fill="white" text-anchor="middle">Child Node 4</text>
        </g>
        
      </svg>
```

I want to know the mechanism behind this. Can anyone explain me, please? Do i have to use transformation in child_nodes group to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Moving child notes to other group in your example messes up output because you are using matrix transformation on one group and not on other - original output it therefore result of child nodes' attributes and transformation on parent node (g).

If you exported SVG from somewhere (fe. Illustrator) it will be easier if you group nodes as required in original file. Or get rid of transform and set child notes accordingly.

I guess it's easier to open SVG in illustrator, do required changes and then export it again, as I did to get the attached snippet.

Other options is to combine groups matrix transformation and line's transformation. Basically your #root_node is just translated (x: 250px, y: 100px). In your case you would just needed to translate line x += 250 & y += 100.

```html
<svg id="svg" width="800" height="600" viewbox="0 0 800 600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g id="root_node" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 250 100)">
          <rect width="200" height="60" rx="5" ry="5">
          </rect>
          <text x="100" y="30" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" fill="white">
            Root Node
          </text>   
        </g>
        <g id="child_node">
          <rect width="180" height="60" x="0" y="0" rx="5" ry="5">
          </rect>
          <rect width="180" height="60" x="500" y="0" rx="5" ry="5">
          </rect>
          <rect width="180" height="60" x="0" y="200" rx="5" ry="5">
          </rect>
          <rect width="180" height="60" x="500" y="200" rx="5" ry="5">
          </rect>
          <text x="100" y="30" font-size="14" fill="white" text-anchor="middle">Child Node 1</text>
          <text x="600" y="30" font-size="14" fill="white" text-anchor="middle">Child Node 2</text>
          <text x="100" y="230" font-size="14" fill="white" text-anchor="middle">Child Node 3</text>
          <text x="600" y="230" font-size="14" fill="white" text-anchor="middle">Child Node 4</text>
          <!-- option 1 -->
          <!-- use transform in lines (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) -->
          <line class="st3" x1="250" y1="100" x2="179.3" y2="29.3" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
          <line class="st3" x1="450" y1="100" x2="520.7" y2="29.3" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
          <line class="st3" x1="250" y1="160" x2="179.3" y2="230.7" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
          <line class="st3" x1="450" y1="160" x2="520.7" y2="230.7" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
          <!-- option 2 -->
          <!-- combine group transform (translate) and line's transform -->
          <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="0" transform="translate(250, 100) rotate(-135)" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
          <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="0" transform="translate(450, 100) rotate(-45)" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
          <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="0" transform="translate(250, 160) rotate(135)" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
          <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="0" transform="translate(450, 160) rotate(45)" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
        </g>
        <g id="edges">
          
        </g>
      </svg>
      
      <svg id="svg" width="800" height="600" viewbox="0 0 800 600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g id="root_node" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 250 100)">
          <rect width="200" height="60" rx="5" ry="5">
          </rect>
          <text x="100" y="30" font-size="14" text-anchor="middle" fill="white">
            Root Node
          </text>
        </g>
        <g id="child_node">
          <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="0" transform="translate(250, 100) rotate(-135)" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
          <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="0" transform="translate(450, 100) rotate(-45)" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
          <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="0" transform="translate(250, 160) rotate(135)" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
          <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="0" transform="translate(450, 160) rotate(45)" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
          
          <rect width="180" height="60" x="0" y="0" rx="5" ry="5">
          </rect>
          <rect width="180" height="60" x="500" y="0" rx="5" ry="5">
          </rect>
          <rect width="180" height="60" x="0" y="200" rx="5" ry="5">
          </rect>
          <rect width="180" height="60" x="500" y="200" rx="5" ry="5">
          </rect>
          <text x="100" y="30" font-size="14" fill="white" text-anchor="middle">Child Node 1</text>
          <text x="600" y="30" font-size="14" fill="white" text-anchor="middle">Child Node 2</text>
          <text x="100" y="230" font-size="14" fill="white" text-anchor="middle">Child Node 3</text>
          <text x="600" y="230" font-size="14" fill="white" text-anchor="middle">Child Node 4</text>
        </g>
        
      </svg>
```

Comment: how is the calculation made for using those lines? Because if i want to show the real data by applying the iteration, how can i show those lines dynamically?

Comment: What calculations? What exactly will be dynamic?

Comment: for example if i have data array as [{name: 'child node1'}, {name: 'child node2'}, {name: 'child node3'}, {name: 'child node4'}] and now i need to show those 4 nodes from this array then i have to iterate the array and use line element which will show 4 lines in respective position.

Comment: Will positions of nodes, texts and lines stay the same all the time. If yes, you can create 4 groups (for 4 child notes) and show them when needed.

Comment: sorry i did not get you.